# C# program that reads in texts until you press a key and then prints it out

Tags: c#, do-while

```
    string text;
    string alltext; //what do I do with this?
    do
    {
        text = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (text!="x");
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

What did I do wrong? Someone on Reddit said that I need another variable to hold all the texts in, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: do you know how to concatenate strings ?

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator

Comment: problem is non of these stop on pressing x, they all need a line with x on its own and pressing enter

Comment: better question is does he know how to declare a variable..? this is not that difficult.. store all the vales into a List<string> and when someone enters the letter To UpperCase `X` , then uses `Console,WriteLine(string.Join(" ", "Your List<strng>")` varible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're new to programming, so I'll try to explain what you want to do.

**You want to store everything you type into a variable until you press X (or so I've understood).**

The variable 'key' will store whatever you type once a cycle (can be anything) - meaning, key will always have a volatile value, because you are changing it everytime it reaches the readline. You append the variable 'key' to your other variable, 'alltext', that is where you have it's previous value + the new value 'key'.   The cycle only ends when you enter 'x' and only 'x'. After that, it will print everything in 'alltext'.

There are many ways to do this, and working with an array is a better and cleaner way, however I'm just adapting what you wrote in a way that you can easily understand.

```
string key = "";
string alltext = "";
do
{
    key = Console.ReadLine();
    alltext += key + "\n ";
} while (key!="x");
Console.WriteLine(alltext);
Console.ReadKey();
```

What I'm doing with "\n" is that I'm adding a new line after that text (let the console know its a new line).

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Code only answers are considered lower quality.  Consider adding an explanation to flesh your answer out and improve its long-term value.

Comment: @Amy true, was editing as you posted it :p

Comment: updated @FakeCaleb

Comment: Doesn't work. Inside the loop it says that "alltext"=Use of unassigned local variable.

Comment: @lapartman Updated, what was wrong was that the variable 'alltext' didn't have an initial value, so the first 'alltext += key + "\n ";' would give an error. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I understand it now!

Comment: @lapartman you're welcome

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted so fast lol.

Comment: Try re-writing the question in a way that makes it within the ruleset the people declared above, and good luck programming!

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are trying to do:  create a string, and keep adding lines to it, until the user hits 'x'.

Now look at what you are doing:  creating a string and then creating that string again with every new line the user types.

Work out what syntax you need to append (add) to the string.  Hint: look up concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string text="";
    string alltext=""; //what do I do with this?
    while (text!="x" || text!="X")
    {
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        alltext+=text;
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(alltext);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

You mean this ?

Comment: You need to initialize alltext

Comment: Fixed in a second. Are you new to programming ?. If yes this could be helpful for you: http://www.learncs.org/

Comment: @FakeCaleb <3 :)

Comment: @Ngine learncs.org maybe? Removed the downvote :)